Martial arts manhwa where the main character is regressed to the past and has a teacher with one arm. Also, his teacher is wanted for stealing
I don't clearly remember the story but I do remember that the main character is regressed to the past and has a teacher with only one arm because he had a curse or something that made him have to cut off his other arm. The teacher is also a wanted person because he stole something important from some factions? (I guess; I don't remember the details.) And they train in some cave; the teacher is strict and sometimes hits the main character while teaching him his techniques. He is also a bit crazy or has a broken mind, kinda like a madman.
Does anyone know what the title of this manhwa is? I really need it. Thank you.
